# Como usar FindviewById E Onclique em um fragment?

Tags: java, imagem, android-fragment

Adicionei duas tab no layout do main activity, e criei duas classe java, uma pra cada tab.  Então tirei os botões  da activity xml  do main activity  e coloquei no layout do fragment, mas vou usar o find view by id na classe java do fragment e não funcionou.

public class FragmentA extends Fragment{

```
    public ImageButton trans ;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_a, container, false );

    trans = (ImageButton)findViewByID(R.id.imagem)

    }
}
```

Comment: No lugar desse ricycler View   usei a imagem :

Answer (score 2):

Essa classe oncreateview tem q retonar um view então pra usar o findviewbyid vc tem q usar o view assim:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentlistavideos, container, false);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.mRecicleview);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: igor Oliveira   eu fiz asim

Comment: Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, Nullable ViewGroup container, Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_a, container, false );
        trans = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.trans);

      return  v;
    }

Comment: Não, vc esta retornando o inflate e só depois você tenta usar o findviewbyid, você tem q passar esse inflate pra um View e usar esse view pra chamar o findviewbyid, compara meu código com o seu

Comment: ta certo, só falta vc colocar o v antes do findviewbyid, fica assim: v.findviewbyid

Comment: ahh então  eu colocaria os botões  e imagems  la no activity do  Recycler view ??

Comment: ahh to comecando a entender

Comment: vou testar aqui

Comment: funcionou.. não ficou vermelho  , mais agora falta mais uma coisa

Comment: public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, Nullable ViewGroup container, Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_a, container, false );
        trans = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.trans);
        trans.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity( new Intent( FragmentA.this, CronogramaActivity.class ) );
            }
        } );
      return  v;
    }
}

Comment: o startActivity ficou vermelho como se nao podesse usar

Comment: o reycleview era só exemplo, pra usar o startactivity vc tb tem q colocar o v antes fica assim: v.startactivity